# What does cell-to-cell variability means?

Tags: cell-biology

I'm reading an [article](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms13788) where they claim that transcriptional bursting could play a role in *cell-to-cell variability*.

> Cell-to-cell variability plays a critical role in cellular responses and decision-making in a population, and transcriptional bursting has been broadly studied by experimental and theoretical approaches as the potential source of cell-to-cell variability.

I was looking for a definition of *Cell-to-cell variability* and I found only the one of *Single-cell variability*

> In cell biology, single-cell variability occurs when individual cells in an otherwise similar population differ in shape, size, position in the cell cycle, or molecular-level characteristics. Such differences can be detected using modern single-cell analysis techniques. Investigation of variability within a population of cells contributes to the understanding of developmental and pathological processes.

Answer (score 1):

I won't ask a question that's related to an article before reading it completely! The answer was in the first paragraph.

> **Cell-to-cell variability** defined as when *genetically identical cells in an identical environment behave differently*, leading to significant consequences in many biological processes from bacterial decision-making to mammalian development.